# I want to find the contents of the en dash on the right

Tags: regex, vba

[image]

I have two sets of data:

```
1977, 74, 5716-5720, doi:10413454   
1967, 8, 8323, doi:10413454
```

I would like to put the second group, no en dash this set of data marked with yellow. I use my regular expression `\d{4}, \d+, \d+(?!-)`

But this does not work. Where am I wrong?

```
Sub Yellow()   
    Dim p As Paragraph, d As Document, reg As Object  
    Set d = ActiveDocument  
    Set reg = CreateObject("VBscript.Regexp")  
    reg.IgnoreCase = False  
    reg.Global = True   
    reg.Pattern = "\d{4}, \d+, \d+(?!-)"   
    For Each p In d.Paragraphs   
        If reg.Execute(p.Range.Text).count = 1 Then  
            m = reg.Execute(p.Range.Text)(0).FirstIndex  
            n = reg.Execute(p.Range.Text)(0).Length   
            With d.Range(p.Range.Start + m + 9, p.Range.Start + m + n)    
                .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow   
                End With  
                End If    
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no way to tell what is wrong with your VBA code, because you did not post any.  ... there is nothing marked in red... you should really check your posting after you submit.

Comment: @jsotola, sorry, I already post my code and picture, Can you give me some guidance?

Comment: You need to show your source and target data format here. Try [RegularExpression101](https://regex101.com/r/jA9rH9/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applied to the input

```
1977, 74, 5716-5720, doi:10413454
```

your regex `\d{4}, \d+, \d+(?!-)` matches `1977, 74, 571`.

Use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to ensure that numbers are always matched in their entirety:

```
\b\d{4}, \d+, \d+\b(?!-)
```

Comment: Thank your help, Boundaries are very useful to me and I will learn，and I already use wildcards to solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Yellow()
With selection.Find
    .Text = "[0-9]{4}, [0-9]{1,}, [0-9]{1,}"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    Do
        .Execute
        If .Found And selection.Range.Next(wdCharacter, 1) <> "" & ChrW(8211) & "" Then
        selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        End If
        If Not .Found Then
        Exit Do
        End If
        Loop
        End With


End Sub
```